# C# async/await - Limit # of calls to async methods / locking

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I come from C++ world so I am very used to locking threads and mutex guarding. Assuming this basic function:

```
async Task BasicProcess() {
    // await time consuming task
}
```

How can I lock this function so only one `BasicProcess` can run at one time?

This is what I want to achieve:

```
async Task BasicProcess() {
    lock (BasicProcessLock) {
         // await time consuming task
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx for an AsyncLock implementation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use SemaphoreSlim(1) for this, A SemaphoreSlim created with (1) will make sure only one thread can get the lock, any other threads that try to get the lock - will wait until the one who got it - release it.
create a private member:

```
private SemaphoreSlim _syncLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
```

Then in your code do:

```
async Task BasicProcess() {

     await _syncLock.WaitAsync(); //Only 1 thread can access the function or functions that use this lock, others trying to access - will wait until the first one released.
     //Do your stuff..
     _syncLock.Release();

 }
```

Comment: Except that this will now block the calling thread, which isn't ideal, if it's really meant to be asynchronous.

Comment: Better use "await _syncLock.WaitAsync();" - otherwise, the thread will be blocked and the task will not run.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I was using Wait() before as well and did not get expected results.

Comment: It's also good for safety to put this in a try/finally. That way you're guaranteed to get a release call even if "// Do your stuff" throws an exception.

Comment: Although this solution works, it's pretty dangerous. The semaphore might be locked for a pretty long time. This is bad for concurrency, but it also increases chances of deadlocks.

If you want to use this solution, then make sure you ALWAYS use `await _syncLock.WaitAsync()` if you need thread synchronization. If you use a synchronous wait, then the current thread might block and the async operation cannot release the semaphore anymore (resulting in a deadlock).

All code that needs to be synchronized should be changed into async methods, which will impact your code pretty heavily!

Comment: what are you talking about. it is await WaitAsync.